# Cast/transpose a data frame string column into a single row

Tags: r

Trying to make this:

```
id |               name
-----------------------
10 |        After Earth
10 | Battle of the Year
10 |   Captain Phillips
12 |             Carrie
12 |  Chernobyl Diaries
```

become this:

```
id |        big_ass_string
--------------------------
10 |  After Earth Battle of the Year Captain Phillips
12 |  Carrie Chernobyl Diaries
```

That is, "cast/transpose" a bunch of strings in a column onto a single row (one big string) grouped by id. I'm using the terms "cast" and "transpose" here, but that's not quite right as neither of those functions will work. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
require(dplyr)

x = data_frame(id = c(10,10,10,12,12), name = c("After Earth","Battle of the Year","Captain Phillips","Carrie","Chernobyl Diaries"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the OP is using `dplyr`.  In that case, we can group by 'id' column and `summarise` to create the variable 'big_ass_string' by `paste`ing the 'name' column.

```
 library(dplyr)
 x %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     summarise(big_ass_string=paste(name, collapse=' '))
 #  id                                  big_ass_string
 #1 10 After Earth Battle of the Year Captain Phillips
 #2 12                        Carrie Chernobyl Diaries
```

Or a `base R` option with `aggregate` would be using the formula method with grouping variable on the RHS of `~`, 'name' variable on the `LHS`, and we specify the `FUN` as `paste` with `collapse = ' '`

```
 aggregate(cbind(big_ass_string=name)~id, x, FUN= paste, collapse=' ')
 #  id                                  big_ass_string
 #1 10 After Earth Battle of the Year Captain Phillips
 #2 12                        Carrie Chernobyl Diaries
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(name~id, FUN='paste', x, collapse=' ')
```

Comment: My bad, I did not refresh the page and didn't see your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically after a data frame, this is less tidy than dplyr as it outputs to a list. Syntactically it's elegant though:

```
tapply(x$name, x$id, paste)
```